# Can't figure out TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, twisted, kivy

I am working on a multi clients/ server chat app that can write input from one client to multi clients. For the client side it's working well, yet for the server side I want to add a part where it can print out the input from the clients on its own screen as well. And when I am working on it I encounter the issue of **init**()takes exactly 3 arguements (2 given) with the line "self.app = app"

Here is my code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.support import install_twisted_reactor
install_twisted_reactor()
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory

class MultiClientEcho(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory, app):
        self.factory = factory
        self.app = app

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        for client in self.factory.clients:
             addtolog = self.factory.app.handle_message(data)
             if addtolog:
               client.transport.write(data)

    def connectionLost(self,reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

class MultiClientEchoFactory(Factory):
    protocol = MultiClientEcho
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
            return MultiClientEcho(self)


class ServerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.label = Label(text="server started\n")
        reactor.listenTCP(8000, MultiClientEchoFactory())
        return self.label

    def handle_message(self, msg):
        self.label.text = "received:  %s\n" % msg
        return msg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServerApp().run()
```

The interesting thing is that I was just adapting from the source code from this site: http://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html , it was working well on its own as well, but once i changed the protocol to MultiClientEcho it immediately resulted in such type error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `__init__` definition for `MultiClientEchoFactory`:

```
def __init__(self, factory, app):
```

That requires three parameters to function (or else it'll throw an error).

You call this line here:

```
return MultiClientEcho(self)
```

Now, the `self` in `__init__` will get defined automatically for you by this instance of `MultiClientEcho`. `factory` will get defined as your instance of `MultiClientEchoFactory`. However, you haven't passed in a parameter for `app`, so python cannot continue.

What you probably want to do is pass your instance of `ServerApp` in the `build` function into the constructor of `MultiClientEchoFactory`:

```
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, MultiClientEchoFactory(self))
```

change the factory to be:

```
def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app
    self.clients = []

def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MultiClientEcho(self, self.app)
```

which will get rid of this error as now you'll be supplying that third `app` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

you are calling `MultiClientEcho(self)` in class `MultiClientEchoFactory` with only one arguments,`factory`:

```
def buildProtocol(self, addr):
            return MultiClientEcho(self)
```

you should try something like

```
class MultiClientEchoFactory(Factory):
    protocol = MultiClientEcho
    def __init__(self,app):
        self.clients = []
        self.app=app

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
            return MultiClientEcho(self,app)


class ServerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.label = Label(text="server started\n")
        reactor.listenTCP(8000, MultiClientEchoFactory(self))
        return self.label

    def handle_message(self, msg):
        self.label.text = "received:  %s\n" % msg
        return msg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServerApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems clear: `MultiClientEcho`'s `__init__` method expects three parameters (factory and app as well as the automatic self) but you're only passing self and factory when you instantiate it in the `buildProtocol` method . Where is it supposed to get `app` from?